# How to get latitude and longitude on current timestamp?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database with a list of timestamps and their corresponding latitudes and longitudes. I am trying to get the longitude and latitude of the most recent timestamp in the database. Here I am able to get the most recent timestamp but my latitude and longitude are not updated and always returns the value of the first timestamp. How do I get it to return from the most recent timestamp?

```
 SELECT delivery.vehicle_id, max(timestamp), latitude, longitude from test
 inner join delivery on delivery.vehicle_id = test.vehicle_id
 where DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%H:%i:%s') <= 
 DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'%H:%i:%s') 
 group by delivery.vehicle_id
```

Desired output: For example latest timestamp for vehicle id 4034 is 13:20 and for vehicle id it is 13:05 so it should get latitude =  22.29098 and longitude = 114.199942 for vehicle id 4034 and for vehicle id 4035 it should get latitude = 22.279973 and longitude = 114.188513. The output needs to be latest latitude and longitude for all vehicles not just one.

```
 delivery table
 vehicle_id    start_time       end_time
 4034          11/1/2014 9:00   11/1/2014 17:00
 4035          11/1/2014 8:00   11/1/2014 16:00

 test table
 timestamp      vehicle_id     latitude      longitude
 11/1/2014 0:00     4034        22.283861   114.146215
 11/1/2014 3:59     4034        22.292902   114.200619
 11/1/2014 8:49     4034        22.28557    114.192797
 11/1/2014 13:20    4034        22.29098    114.199942
 11/1/2014 13:23    4034        22.290495   114.196016
 11/1/2014 0:08     4035        22.293131   114.200671
 11/1/2014 6:02     4035        22.293043   114.200737
 11/1/2014 9:35     4035        22.278188   114.153437
 11/1/2014 13:05    4035        22.279973   114.188513
 11/1/2014 14:33    4035        22.277418   114.17543
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Please post the table structure for both tables.  And sample data would really help your question.

Comment: Do you have access to latest version of MySQL (version 8.0.2 and above) ?

Comment: Also, add the expected output to your question (based on the given sample data).

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I included my desired output in the description

Comment: Should not be this `11/1/2014 13:23    4034        22.290495   114.196016` and `11/1/2014 14:33    4035        22.277418   114.17543` the latests registers with max timestamp for the vehicles? Why you say it is `13:20` and `13:05`.

Comment: @D.Smania Yes because everything takes places on 11/1/2014  hence I only check for time since the date is constant, which is why I placed 13:20 and 13:05 respectively.

Comment: But `13:23 is greater than 13:20` and `14:33 is greater than 13:05` respectively. should not be `13:23` and `14:33` the latest ones?

Comment: @D.Smania Yes I am aware I just want to know how to output the latitude and longitude corresponding to the timestamp. Just gave those timestamps as examples and what should be outputted.

Comment: Please, confirm that the expected output from your sample of data are these ones respectively: `11/1/2014 13:23 4034 22.290495 114.196016` for vehicle with id `4034` and `11/1/2014 14:33 4035 22.277418 114.17543` for vehicle with id `4035`. I know how to approach this, but I need this confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an approach like this one, you first need to made a subquery with the latest timestamps for every `vehicle_id`, and then join this subquery on the proper columns for get the rest of the information (*i.e, the related latitude and longitude*):

```
SELECT
    t.vehicle_id,
    t.timestamp,
    t.latitude,
    t.longitude
FROM
    test AS t
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
         vehicle_id, MAX(timestamp) AS maxT
     FROM
         test
     GROUP BY
         vehicle_id) AS max_log ON max_log.vehicle_id = t.vehicle_id
                                AND max_log.maxT = t.timestamp
```

**Note** this will only works good if the timestamp data is normalized, like on next sample, or if you use one of the available MySQL types available for this: [DATETIME or TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

```
test table
timestamp         vehicle_id  latitude    longitude
11/01/2014 00:00  4034        22.283861   114.146215
11/01/2014 03:59  4034        22.292902   114.200619
11/01/2014 08:49  4034        22.28557    114.192797
11/01/2014 13:20  4034        22.29098    114.199942
11/01/2014 13:23  4034        22.290495   114.196016
11/01/2014 00:08  4035        22.293131   114.200671
11/01/2014 06:02  4035        22.293043   114.200737
11/01/2014 09:35  4035        22.278188   114.153437
11/01/2014 13:05  4035        22.279973   114.188513
11/01/2014 14:33  4035        22.277418   114.17543
```

You can play with a working example on next link:

[DB Fiddle Example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sNStkaWrXHkkg6ENh5CZW/0)

Comment: Hi this is super helpful thank you so much!